# Randomized groups for A/B testing

Tags: clustering, ab-test

I have the dataset where the dimension = 10 and number of samples = 20. Let's denote the features by $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{10}$. I'd like to analyze the effect of $x_2$ on $x_1$. I applied the following concept which is similar to A/B testing to solve this problem.

First, I clustered the samples into two groups based on their values of $x_2$, with those above the $median(x_2)$ being in group A and others in group B. In order to reduce the bias, I also want both group A and B to be randomized groups. That is, for each group, I want features $x_3, x_4, ..., x_{10}$ to be as diverse (randomized) as possible. To use the analogy in A/B testing, if $x_3$ is age, I want group A can have samples ranging from 10 years old to 70, and likewise for group B. Last, for features other than $x_1$ or $x_2$, there should be minimal differences between group A and group B at the aggregated level.

The above reasoning can be simplified into the following objectives:

Form group A and B from the dataset where

1. $avg(x_{A2}) - avg(x_{B2})$ is maximized
2. $avg(x_{Ai}) - avg(x_{Bi})$ is minimized for $i = 3, 4, ..., 10$

After the groups are formed, we can calculated some summary statistics of $x_1$ like $avg(x_1)$ for each group to see whether they are different.

I am wondering if there are better ways to form the above groups. I tried to simply plot boxplots for each group, and swap samples to make both groups similar in terms of $x_3, ..., x_{10}$, but this is not a systematic way. Although the effect of $x_2$ on $x_1$ can be found simply by regressing $x_1$ on all other features, or by some pairwise statistics like correlation coefficients or mutual information, I wonder how it can be solved via the above approach. Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods for A/B-testing: stratification and randomization. 
The idea of the first is— you just select the users by parameters you think matters for your test: age, gender, location, etc. And the idea of randomization— you just select the users randomly, at some moment your sample group will be a very similar to your general population.
That's it.